# C# tabControl DrawFixed

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, tabs, tabcontrol

I'm using TabControl and I have DrawFixed. I just want only draw the tabs not the panel under it.

[image: tabControl panel]

How can I remove it?

Also I'd like to ask, can I change tabs size? I've long text which I'd like see all if it's selected but I'd like see it cropped if it's not active.

I've following in draw event, but it always draws the tab in the same size.

```
if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
}
else
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
    text = text.Length > 10 ? text.Substring(0, 10) + "..." : text;
}

e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + 17, e.Bounds.Top + 3);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I ask the intent of using OwnerDrawFixed?

TabControl is a difficult control to tweak, it uses a legacy drawing method and has known bugs to boot. Also are you inheriting and customising the TabControl or just using it as is?

Comment: @JCollins I'm drawing on it some images. It's chat window. There is user availability, name and it indicate new message by message icon and orange background. I only have my own TabPages. TabControl has no change.

Comment: Where exactly is the draw event you are overriding?

If you were to override TabControl and create your own inheriting control, you could use SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True) in the constructor then override OnPaint and/or OnPaintBackground then you will have complete control. Though then you will be responsible for drawing the tabs.

Comment: @JCollins I'm using DrawItem event for TabControl if you mean this. I don't have my own TabControl and I'll think if I really want to do this it's going to be complicated. Can I ask you about part 2 of my question: How can I resize inactive Tabs which have cropped text? And do you know about some site where is shown some styling in Draw event? I'd like use the default tab style but also I'd like own Drawing. So some inspiration how to set tabs style.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're asking why the tabs aren't resizing for variable length text? TabControls have very little control over size tab size, either it is fixed like in your case, or the system automatically sets the size. There is basically no way, inheriting or no, to override that behaviour.

Regarding drawing, again either you take full control or leave it up to the system. I have spent a bunch of time trying to customise the tab control and it's pretty painful. No specific links but sourceforge is my go to for projects people have done.

Comment: @JCollins I used `SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)` and I used some code to style component. But I'd like use own `OnDrawItem` event. Couse I've in my app `MainForm` some variables and images which I want to use in Drawing event. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Chronologically in your question, you have asked how to get rid of that bar at the top. If you insisted on using 'faux' tab pages where the tabs merely control content of the fixed set of controls, then shrinking the height of the tab control to a point where that isn't visible is probably an acceptable solution. I just tried it and with some tweaking it looks mostly what I think you are after. For the record I'd recommend actually using the tab pages as intended, that is as hosts to controls, even if you make a custom control that brings together all the controls you want visible. This will fit the tab paradigm much better.

For the second point you'd like to resize the tabs. Impossible. The framework gives two options for `DrawStyle`, Normal and `OwnerDrawFixed`. `Normal` allows Windows to set the tab size based on the text and font, `OwnerDrawFixed` means the tab size is completely fixed. There is no  more control over this. `OwnerDrawFixed` however gives you access to the `OnDrawItem` event which is what you are wanting to use for painting the tabs themselves.

It now seems you've bitten the bullet and set UserPaint to True which means you are now doing all of the drawing. I recommend at this point to set `DrawStyle` back to `Normal`, then you can kludge some behind-the-scenes text to have Windows control the tab widths automatically. I will warn this won't be very robust since everyone has different font settings and a few pixels off and nothing will draw right.

So here I'll point out `TabControl.GetTabRect(index As Integer)`, the method you can use to get the bounding rectangle of a given tab. I use this in a loop over all the tab indices and then do all the drawing I need for the tab within the rectangle provided from each tab. This means I don't need to use `OwnerDrawFixed` to get the bounds to paint within.

However still if you want better control, you're 80% the way to just implementing exactly whatever control you want to see, starting from either `Control` or `UserControl`. A similar look could be achieved from overlapping buttons with some logic to paint and lay them out. Then you could get all the text appearance you want also. I considered the same myself but didn't because I am still hosting `TabPages`. Since you're free from that it would be even easier...

Comment: In what method do you loop over all tabs and do the drawing?

Answer (score 0):

Just use page text default property it will auto fix tab size for you according to the size of text.. then paint your text by your self .. if you still want additional space for painting image or some thing else  then use padding which is the property of tab control not the tab page. i hope it will help full for you.